# measure capacity of a battery after charged

Tags: batteries, measurement, charge

I have two AAA rechargeable batteries that claim to have 550Mha capacity. My first question is, how can I measure the Mha and make sure the battery is fully charged?

Second question and related somehow to the previous one:
I have a charger that reads DC 1.4V -- 80 -100Ma x2 (AAA) so I think it provides 100Mah (my batteries would take about 6 hours to complete charge if I'm not mistaken.

Thank you,

Matias.

Comment: End of charge detection depends on chemistry. Also, the efficiency if far lower than 100%, in order to have 1000 mA in the battery you'd have to put like 1500 mA in it (also depends on chemistry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ensure that the battery receives a full charge by charging it for significantly longer than is (theoretically) required. If your charger puts out 80mA then in 6 hours it will have delivered 480mAh - which may not be enough. You should charge it for around 8 hours to be sure.

Another way to tell when the battery has reached full charge is to measure its temperature. While charging, most of the electrical energy is stored chemically (though the chemical reaction when charging NiMH is exothermic, so so some heating will occur with this type of battery). Once the battery reaches full charge it can no longer store energy, so it must dissipate it all as heat. So check the temperature every few minutes, and when it starts to heat up rapidly you know it is charged.

To accurately measure the capacity you must discharge the battery until it is 'flat' (0.9V per cell) at a known current. Then multiply the current (in mA) by the time (in hours) to get the capacity in mAh.

If you use a resistor the current will gradually decline as the voltage drops. You need to account for this or else the capacity measurement will be inaccurate. So periodically measure the current (or measure voltage across the resistor and calculate the current draw), calculate the capacity for each time segment, then add them all up to get the total.

Alternatively you could just use a [charger](http://www.skyrc.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=20&product_id=200) which does it all for you.

Answer (score 1):

Most battery capacity ratings are based on a 20-hour discharge time.

So: divide your rated battery capacity by 20 and calculate the resistor value that is required to achieve that current.

Note that the battery discharge voltage curve is NOT flat but the total error will be fairly small.  In other words, if you choose the resistor value to that you achieve the desired current when the battery is fully charged, that current will decay as the battery terminal voltage decays.

Now charge your cells completely and connect your chosen discharge resistor.  Then take a voltage reading on each cell every half hour or so until the cell terminal voltage reaches the end-of-life voltage.

To make this easy, you can build a simple data-logger that will automatically take those voltage readings for you and save them to a file.  You could also build the data logger such that it disconnects the load resistor when end-of-life voltage is reached so as to not damage the cell.